# About a proverb students have on their diaries

Tags: proverbs

The students I have keep a diary. The two sentences below are written on those diaries.

> 小さな積み重ねが、大きな差となる
>
> Small stacking makes big difference.

That English sounds awkward to me. It is absolutely google translated and copy/pasted. But since my Japanese and knowledge of their proverbs(if that sentence is one) is limited, I was wondering if the below proverbs would mean what they meant with the Japanese sentence.

> Many a little makes a mickle.
>
> A journey of a thousand miles begins with one single step.

Apart from these two, are there any other proverbs that can convey the meaning of that Japanese sentence? Or if I am wrong, what could be the correct proverb? I don't need a direct translation like;

Many small amounts accumulate to make a large amount.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「小{ちい}さな積{つ}み重{かさ}ねが、大{おお}きな差{さ}となる」

is definitely ***not*** a proverb.

It is only a "regular" sentence, which seems to be a rephrasing of the "***real***" proverb:

> 「塵{ちり}も積{つ}もれば山となる」

which indeed means:

"Many a little makes a mickle." or "A journey of a thousand miles begins with one single step."

Other Japanese proverbs with similar meanings would include:

> 「ローマは一日{いちにち}にして成{な}らず」 ("Rome was not built in a day.")
>
> 「千里{せんり}の道{みち}も一歩{いっぽ}から」 ("A journey of a thousand miles begins with one single step."
> )

I just used the term "Japanese proverbs" myself, but many of the proverbs used in Japanese actually come from ancient China, Rome, Greece, etc.

Comment: Thank you. And that "small stacking" sentence was やっぱり google translate. This will be on the next topic and a nice lesson to why they should not depend completely on translation applications. I think  "a journey of a thousand miles begins with one single step" would look much cooler on their diaries.

Comment: So the Japanese proverb would be something like "Pile enough dirt and you can make a mountain." right?

Comment: Gather enough drops of water and eventually you'll have an ocean.